# How to handle fragment state using viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel, android-livedata

class MediaViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
    val loadMediaAlbumStatus: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<PhotosItem>>> = MutableLiveData()

    private val coroutinesExceptionHandler =
        CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
            loadMediaAlbumStatus.postValue(Resource.Error(throwable))
        }

    fun loadEachAlbumImages(context: Context, bucketId: String) =
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutinesExceptionHandler) {
            val photoList: MutableList<PhotosItem> = mutableListOf()
            loadMediaAlbumStatus.postValue(Resource.Loading())

            withContext(IO) {

                val cursor: Cursor? =
                    MediaLoader.loadMedia(context, bucketId, MediaType.PHOTO)
                cursor?.moveToFirst()
                val pathColumnIndex = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaLoader.COLUMN_DATA)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                    val path = cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex)
                    val name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
                    val photo = PhotosItem(name, path)
                    photoList.add(photo)
                    cursor.moveToNext()
                }
                cursor.close()
                loadMediaAlbumStatus.postValue(Resource.Success(photoList))
            }
        }
```

I am trying to get media photos based on bucket id passed in function
its working but when,

I want to maintain a selection mode state even after the fragment destroyed
so whn i come back to each folder in gallery the selection mode needs to maintain.

here is my adapter class

```
private const val TAG = "AlbumAdapter"

class MediaAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val photoSelect: (PhotosItem) -> Unit,
    private val photoDeselect: (PhotosItem) -> Unit
) : ListAdapter<PhotosItem, MediaAdapter.MediaHolder>(DiffCallBack()) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MediaHolder {
        return MediaHolder(
            ItemPhotosBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MediaHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class MediaHolder(private val itemMedia: ItemPhotosBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemMedia.root) {

        init {
            itemMedia.root.setOnClickListener {
                val clickPhoto = getItem(adapterPosition)
                clickPhoto.isSelected = !clickPhoto.isSelected
                if (clickPhoto.isSelected) photoSelect(clickPhoto)
                else photoDeselect(clickPhoto)
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: PhotosItem) {
            itemMedia.overlayImage.visibility = if (item.isSelected) VISIBLE else INVISIBLE
            Glide.with(context).load(Uri.fromFile(File(item.path))).into(itemMedia.imageView)
        }

    }


    class DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PhotosItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PhotosItem, newItem: PhotosItem): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem


        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PhotosItem, newItem: PhotosItem): Boolean =
            oldItem.path == newItem.path


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually you should hold your list in `viewModel` and in every select item turn some variable like `selected` in your data class `true`. register observer to your `LiveData` list and set adapter data.

Comment: I just find the solution after playing around. using live data sometimes adapter not notifying of data change like when boolean modified from false to true

Comment: Yes, LiveData could not notifying value changed when a value of internal class change. You can write extension for livedata to set value to livedata to notifying observers.